# How can we rollout Salesforce cpq in production for some or limited users only,as we are installing it over our existing sales cloud implementation?

Tags: salesforcedx, opportunity, cpq, quote, sales-cloud

We're about to start Salesforce CPQ Implementation, after sales cloud. Users are using sales cloud and are using Opportunity to add products. Now we want to start CPQ pilot for some users, but what i know is as soon as we install cpq package and authorize new cpq calculation, users will not be able to add products directly on opportunity(as they are currently doing). They have to use quote and quote lines.We dont want to have impact on other users .
Is there any way we can achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CPQ will only be available to the users who are assigned CPQ licenses. Other users can continue to use Opportunity & Opportunity Products. Technically, all users can use Opportunity & Opportunity Products irrespective of CPQ licenses. But, once a primary quote is created then the Opportunity Products will be overwritten by Quote Lines.

In short, there shouldn't be any issue with your use case. You can continue to use both ways in the same org based on license assignment.

Comment: Thanks @Shwetha